# How to lose as little heat as possible to the surroundings from an endothermic reaction?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-chemistry

For an experiment, I'm adding several substances (as powders) to hydrogen chloride, and measuring the temperature changes to calculate enthalpy. What is a container I could perform it in (other than a styrofoam cup) that would minimise the heat lost to the surroundings?

I looked up using a vacuum flask of some sort, but would that be appropriate for this sort of reaction? The temperature is being measured via a temperature probe.

Comment: In endothermic reaction, if you start it at room temp., you'd have heat gain from the surroundings.

Comment: Yeah, some are endothermic and some are exo. I'm trying to minimise the effect of heat losses/gains on the change temperature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What is the scale?
2. What is the budget?

[Reactors are available](http://shop.faust.ch/QSRCH.HTM?UID=550055125b5d000000000000&KEYVAL=9.142+106) from 250 mL up.

It might be cheaper to place a flask in a cut-off bottom of a suitable PE bottle and insulate it with PU foam from a DIY market.

**UPDATE**

A small Dewar cylinder might be an option too. 
The [model 00C](https://de.vwr.com/store/catalog/product.jsp?catalog_number=478-4102) has a volume of 100 mL and lids are available too. Usually, these Dewars are used to store liquid nitrogen and cooling mixtures (2-propanol + dry ice, etc.) so I don't know how resistant the lid is towards $\ce{HCl}$ over time. In addition, this setup isn't as tight as a flask with hollow stoppers and/or a silicone seal if that's an issue.

Comment: The scale is pretty small, only $50cm^3$ of HCl. Would a vacuum flask, the sort shown [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/vacfla.html), reduce heat loss?

Comment: @deusy The Dewars might work too. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! One last thing that you might have a suggestion for: What is the best way to stir the reaction once I add the powder? I'm measuring temperature with a temperature probe, but stirring with that is probably not a good idea because it may affect the temperature recordings.

Comment: Does the powder dissolve immediately? Are measurements  on an inhomogenenous sample useful? Can you measure the temperature before, then add the powders to a stirred solution, stop stirring and start the real measurements? Maybe this is good enough for a separate question on [tag:experimental-chemistry].

Comment: The new question is [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27870/stirring-the-reaction-between-hydrogen-chloride-and-a-powdered-substance).